# Is there a way to create global CSS variables?

Tags: css

## Global CSS variables

I have multiple CSS files in my project

[image: Project directory example]

I don't want to set the variables in each CSS file, but I would like to access them from every file.

Comment: CSS variables aren't JS or C++ variables. There is no *global* concept. It's all about selector and scope. You define variable for elements and it is independent from the number of files. If the selector apply (or there is inheritance) then you have the variable

Comment: Ortiga's answer should be marked as it is most accurate and complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import another CSS file from a CSS using:

```
@import "path/variables.css";
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Comment: @Gian has this solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a `globals.css` file in there somewhere. Add your **CSS Variables.** `@import` that file into the others where needed.